# Table Maker's Dilemma

Tags: logarithms, transcendental-equations, trigonometry

I am trying to understand the TMD based on this [doc](http://www.vinc17.org/research/slides/aoc2000-11.pdf).

As per my understanding,

For transcendental functions i..e (log2 log10 1oge, exp,sin, cos,tan...) **the exact value for an input cannot be computed**.

So assume y = f(x) where f - transcendental function. We will always compute the approximation to f which is y".

Furthermore, the document defines Table Maker's dilemma as follows,

> Does one obtain the **rounding of f(x)** by **rounding y" ? **
>
> Not Always possible if y has the following form:
>
> - in rounding to nearest mode
> - in rounding towards 0,+infinity, -infinity modes
>
> This problem is called Table Maker's Dilemma (TMD)

So my confusion is

- what does it mean by an exact value  ?
- if f(x) exact value cannot be computed, how can you say that rounding of f(x)?
- I cannot understand how does approximation to f(x) - y" is computed , no mention of approximation?
- what does it mean by rounding of f(x) should be equivalent to rounding of y" (approximation)
- how does the point 3 is negated when y=f(x) is very close to exact number?

Can you please explain what exactly the problem is ?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Table-maker.27s_dilemma and http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/Intro-to-TMD.htm.

Comment: Here's a concrete example: "log(+0x1.ac50b409c8aeep+8) = 0x60f52f37aecfcfffffffffffffffeb...p-200 There are 62 consecutive 1-bits in that number, and at least 4 × 13 + 62 + 1 = 115 bits must be computed correctly in order to determine the correctly-rounded 53-bit result."

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, the table-maker's dilemma as described in the sources listed in the comments [Wikipedia Table-Maker's dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Table-maker.27s_dilemma) and [Intro to TMD](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/Intro-to-TMD.htm) refers to computing in advance, given the IEEE rounding mode (nearest, truncate, floor, ceiling), the operation to be performed, and the range of arguments, the greatest number of significant figures `n` in order to ensure `m` bits of accuracy.

Pretend we have a function `f` and a floating-point scalar `x`. `y = f(x)` is not guaranteed to be a dyadic rational with a small enough denominator to be exactly represented by a floating point number, so instead we calculate $y^*$, which is accurate to `m` binary places. $y^*$ has a relative error of $2^{-m}$, so we really have an interval $[\;(1-y^*2^{-m})\;y^*,\space(1+y^*2^{-m})\;y^*\;]$.

We can divide the real line into disjoint, contiguous intervals that each round to a particular floating point number. The question is then, how do we pick an `m` in advance such that, for each interval we get by applying `f` to a floating-point scalar `x`, every value in that interval rounds to the same floating point number with `n` significant figures.

Comment: Thank you Greg, this is informative, i will go through this!

Comment: Great answer, but the $m$ and $n$ seem opposite in the first and the last paragraph.